# Stop Pretty default Mongo Shell (mongosh)

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I jsut installed the new version, which is mongosh, and pretty printing is by default. When I am looking at multiple records, I find it inconvenient. Does anyone know how to turn off pretty print by default in mongosh …or at all?

I didn’t know about the mongo shell settings. I spent all of yesterday looking, so thank you very much!
There doesn’t seem to be an option that does exactly that. Perhaps the new shell design doesn’t allow for it

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to unset the pretty print settings as per [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/stop-pretty-default-mongo-shell-mongosh/205370). I checked the `DBQuery` object (`console.log(DBQuery);`) in the mongosh shell and couldn't find any way to modify it.